# (25/10) compared to (25//10) in python

Tags: python

why does one give a different end result than the other in python. When I type in print(25/10) the result is 2.5.
Yet when I type print(25//10) it is 2. Could anyone tell me why?

Comment: They are different operators. / is division, // is 'floor division'. It's worth mentioning that you must be using python 3, in python 2 all standard division was a floor division

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.2.html#pep-238-changing-the-division-operator for more info

Answer (score 0):

// used for Floor Division - The division of operands where the result is the quotient in which the digits after the decimal point are removed.